# How to access the Windows 10 Storage Space in another Windows notebook?

Tags: windows-10, storage-spaces

I created a windows 10 storage space in an external USB storage connected to my Windows 10 Pro. I've lost my Windows 10 installation on my notebook. My backups were in the Storage Space (external USB storage). I thought it was just connect the usb storage in other Windows 10 machie and my data would be there. The fact is that the other Windows 10 Pro notebook does not recognize the Storage Space.

Is there a process I need to do in order to the new notebook recognize the Storage Space?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Storage Spaces are an extension of your User and Users are very highly secure in Windows 10.  That is why your other machine does not recognize the files.

Attach another USB drive to your main computer. Make a folder on it called (say) c:\temp and you can assign "Everyone" permission to c:\temp.

Now copy the files you need from Storage Spaces to the new USB drive in C:\temp.

Safely disconnect everything and then attach the new USB drive to your notebook.

Recover the files you need.

Comment: Thank you John, I fixed the problem, It was related to the Windows version in the new machine.

Answer (score 0):

what happened was that the new Windows 10 Pro machine was not in the latest Windows 10 Pro version. After I upgraded the manchine for the lastest windows version the Storage Space was recognized and I could work with it normally.